# split a python string of letters and exponents

Tags: python, python-3.x, math

I have a string containing the literal part of a monomial. I should try to divide the letters from their exponents by inserting them into lists and assign exponent 1 if a letter does not have it. 
strings are like that `a^5bc^0.5`

```
str = a^5bc^0.5
letters, exponents = split_monomial(str)
print(letters) # ['a','b','c']
print(exponents) # [5,1,0.5]
```

this is what i tried but i thing that there is a conceptual error

```
_ = True
numeric_cache = ''
        for i in range(len(litteral_part)):
            if litteral_part[i] in letters:
                if i > 0:
                    if not _:
                        litteral_e.append(float(numeric_cache))
                    litteral_e.append(1.0)
                _ = True
                litteral.append(litteral_part[i])
            elif litteral_part[i] == '^':
                _ = False
            elif litteral_part[i] in numbers:
                if not _:
                    numeric_cache = numeric_cache + litteral_part[i]
```

litteral_part is str

Comment: Some quick n dirty regex can do it:
`s = [float(_s ) for _s in re.findall("[0-9.]*", s) if _s != ""]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `re` module with some post-processing for this task:

```
import re

s = 'a^5bc^0.5'

letters, exponents = zip(*re.findall(r'([a-z])(?:\^(\-?\d+\.?\d*))?', s))

letters = list(letters)
exponents = [1 if n == '' else float(n) for n in exponents]

print(letters)
print(exponents)
```

Prints:

```
['a', 'b', 'c']
[5.0, 1, 0.5]
```